# Org included child documents and macro expansion

Tags: org-mode

I have a master doc (`master.org`) and child docs (`A.org`, `B.org`, etc.) I have a macro which uses the name of the current file to create chapters, so for example when I do `{{{sections}}}`, the macro evaluates an ELisp function to get the name of the file and then creates appropriate (e.g. `* A - Intro`).

Now, I want to know if there is a simple way to make this work when including child documents. Obviously, if I use this macro in `A.org`, then include it from `master.org`, the macro will expand into  `* Master - Intro`.

Any way of evaluating the macros with the name of the file they were in?

Comment: I don't think there is any simple way. Look at `org-export-as`: it copies the file you are exporting to a new buffer, and the first thing it does is it expands `#+INCLUDE` keywords. After that, there are no child documents: it is all one big buffer. Macros are expanded after that, so they don't have any filenames to  play with (other than perhaps the name of the top level file).

Comment: I see, thanks Nick!